# What is a faster way to log events using Webservices

Tags: performance, web-services, asynchronous, ejb

I have an application that must log all events that the user does in a remote database, so,I´ve choice to use the webservice format (the application call the webservice with the event parameters).

So, i did a remote EJB to perform that, but it is running with a bad performance, because the application needs to wait for the webservice´s response to proceed the request.

Is JMS an alternative?

What you suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- JMS will be much lighter & can asynchronously process the events. They can be used to capture application events or audit logs for the activities occurring in the system. Can send a message to a queue with proper details & those can be fetched at receiving end to process further.
- If you are using EJB-3.1, then can annotate your method with `@Asynchronous` which returns `AsyncResult` implementation of `Future` which can be used to retrieve result, but can also be used with methods returning void.

Comment: @user1266554 To which one are you referring & what have you chosen for logging.